# Is there a way to trigger Fancybox to auto-open when calling .fancybox()

Tags: jquery, fancybox, swfobject

I'm trying to get fancybox 1.3.4 to automatically open when it's called. We used to use:

```
jQuery("a.vidHelp").fancybox(fbOptions).trigger('click');
```

However this doesn't seem to work any more. The fancybox has a div in it which uses swfObject to load.

Neither swfObject nor fancybox seem to have triggers for when they finish loading so I am currently using this:

```
var checkFancybox = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (jQuery("object#flashContent").length) {
        jQuery("a.vidHelp").trigger("click");
        clearInterval(checkFancybox);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Which checks for the flash object to be created and the triggers a click.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: swfobject has an optional callback function that can be triggered upon successful embed

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted that!

Answer (score 0):

My code is like

In HTML

```
<a id="btn" title="OPEN FANCYBOX" href="#hiddenPre">
<div style="display:none"><pre id="hiddenPre">dummy</pre></div>
```

In JS

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#hiddenPre").text(textYouWantToShow);
});

//fancybox binding
$("a#btn").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});
```

and in your case, you just need to call

```
$("#hiddenPre").text(textYouWantToShow);
```

should do the trick